# Redirecting bash output to a path stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to redirect my output to a file which has its path stored in a variable but I cant get it to work.

```
LOG_TEST="~/AVDS/logs/${HOSTNAME}_testlog.log"

echo "foo" >> ~/AVDS/logs/${HOSTNAME}_testlog.log
echo "bar" >> $LOG_TEST
```

The "foo" line will work fine but the "bar" line returns the error:

```
./testarea.sh: line 9: ~/AVDS/logs/tvpc-office_testlog.log: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Two best-practices notes, by the way -- variables local to your script (as opposed to built-in variables that impact the configuration of the shell itself or system environment variables) should have at least one lower-case character; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace. Second, consider quoting your expansions: `>>"$log_test"` vs `>>$log_test`; that way your command will work even if the name contains spaces.

Comment: Also, if you're running commands with `>>$log_test` multiple times in your script, that's re-opening the output file once per command -- very inefficient compared to just opening it once and reusing the file descriptor.

Comment: For instance, you could put `exec 3>"$log_test"` once at the top of your script, and then whenever you want output from `some_command` go there, do so with a redirection such as `some_command >&3`; that way there's just one file handle reused throughout the script.

Comment: Thats good to know, thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
If the script gets interrupted will it still write all the output to the file up until that point?

Comment: For subprocesses so redirected, definitely, since their output is flushed on close. For in-process, buffered writes, everything since the last flush could be lost, but I'm having trouble thinking of any case where you _could_ have a write not flushed on end-of-command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tilde expansion only happens when unquoted.

Get in the habit of using `$HOME`, not `~`, in scripts.

Comment: Ah! Definitely not where I thought the problem was going to be. Thanks!